# Python - "for" loops only 2 times (should not)

Tags: python

I'm writing this code and I can't get to grasp why my for loop is not working properly. When given a value that is not correct, the loop works fine the first time, but the second time it just skips to the next part of code.

```
# Defining the way the pattern should be inputted
def pattern_input():
    try:
        choice = int(raw_input("Enter number here: "))
        if choice > 2:
            print "Please enter a valid number\n"
            loop = 1
        else:
            loop = 2
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a valid number\n"
        loop = 1
        choice = 3  # To have a correct value of choice
    return loop, choice

# User chooses what kind of pattern s/he wants to use
print "What kind of album is this?"
print "1 - A single artist album\n2 - A various artists album"
loop, choice = pattern_input()
for loop in range(1):
    loop, choice = pattern_input()
```

Comment: In fact, it loops once, not twice :) `range(1) = [0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for loop in range(1):
```

`range(1)` is a sequence, and this loops over the elements of that sequence. Modifying `loop` in the loop body has no effect. If you want to loop until the user enters something valid, use a `while`:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    valid, choice = pattern_input()
```

Comment: Modifying `loop` inside the loop-body has an effect, but apparently not the desired one, as soon as the next value is assigned to it.

Comment: Hmm, I used for because LPTHW said to use while only for neverending loops...
But it works, thanks!